# ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: hadoop, ssh, cygwin, port, master-slave

**Edited**:-

i have done with single node cluster on two different machine,I have made one as master(192.168.1.1) and other m/c as slave(192.168.1.2), I am successfully able to ping between two machine,I have made the following changes to get into 2 node cluster Update :-

/etc/hosts on both machines  **hosts.allow**

```
All :  Ashish-PC 192.168.1.1 : allow
All  : slave 192.168.1.2 : allow
```

master file with

```
  Ashish-PC
```

slaves file with

```
  Ashish-PC 
  slave
```

I am getting an error while copying local host public key to remote host(slave): **port 22**

```
 ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@slave
 /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any    that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
```

as well as when i start all dfs at master services then also :-

```
 bin/start-dfs.sh
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-Ashish-namenode-  Ashish-PC.out
slave: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
Ashish-PC: starting secondarynamenode, logging to       /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-Ashish-secondarynamenode-Ashish-PC.out
slave: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
```

while copying key:-

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@slave
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh: connect to host slave port 22: Connection timed out
```

i have used cygwin and ssh is working fine on both the PC and I went through some suggestion to change the port number 22(because of ISP problem) but i dont want do that just [because](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/03/12/why-putting-ssh-on-another-port-than-22-is-bad-idea/).
thanks in advance for your help and response.

Comment: this should probably be done before the import by preprocessing the file in, for example, awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow master to communicate through Windows Firewall by adding sshd in home as well as public...[image]

make sure your sshd services are started on each node for communication.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me:**

1.

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

2.
Remove the comment

```
#Port 22 
#Protocol 2
```